# How can I check if bit value is greater than 1 with TRY_CONVERT sql function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms-2012

I'm using **sql server managment studio 2012**

What I'm trying to do is check if string value is a bit if it is then I want to check if this value is greater than 1. here is my code:

```
(TRY_CONVERT(bit, '2') IS NULL OR TRY_CONVERT(bit, '2') > 1)
```

For this sample purpose I hardcoded there a string with value.

Anyone can tell me why this doesn't work I mean second condition.

Comment: A `bit` can never be greater than `1`. `cast(2 as bit)` just gives `1`

Comment: Bit can never be greater then 1. Any positive int = 1 when converted to bit.

Comment: I think it is a `char` or `varchar(1)`

Comment: Ok @MartinSmith Thanks your comment was enough to answer this question:) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`bit` fields in SQL Server can only have one of three values: `1`, `0` or `NULL` therefore checking for values greater than 1 is invalid.

So to resolve your issue I would consider this method

```
SELECT Convert(bit, CASE WHEN your_field IN ('1', '0') THEN your_field END) As valid_bit
```